# Find unique names containing consecutive repeating consonants

Tags: command-line

I'm just starting to learn how to use Ubuntu and I am having some difficulties.

I am supposed to use back-referencing to find unique girl names containing consecutive repeating consonants in a file of baby names that I have stored as `allnames.txt`.

I used:

```
$ cat allnames.txt | cut -f5 | sort | uniq | grep -i 'bb\|cc\|dd\|ff\|gg\|hh\|jj\|kk\|ll\|mm\|nn\|pp\|qq\|rr\|ss\|tt\|vv\|ww\|xx\|yy\|zz'
```

and it looks like it worked, but is there an easier (shorter), and possibly more accurate way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `-u` for unique sorting:

```
cat allnames.txt | cut -f5 | sort -u | grep -Ei '([bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxyz])\1'
```

Here we are assuming that the fields are separated by the tab character (e.g., `This\tIs\tA\tFriend\tCarlos`), since this is the default delimiter for `cut`.

If you really need to do this frequently, you might want to write a script, of course.

Comment: have you checked it?

Comment: @souravc I just edited a mistake :-)

Comment: IMHO `grep -Ei '([bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxyz])\1'` is the correct one. `()` has important role here.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this one:

```
cat allnames.txt | cut -f5 | sort | uniq | grep -Ei '(\w)\1+'
```

Where `-E` means allow use of extended [regexp](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression)

`\w` means any *Alphanumeric characters plus _*

`\1` reference to previous character founded by `(\w)` one more time

`+` means *Matches the preceding element one or more times. For example, ab+c matches "abc", "abbc", "abbbc", and so on, but not "ac".*

For consonants only:

```
cat allnames.txt | cut -f5 | sort | uniq | grep -Ei '([qrtpsdfghjklzxcvbnm])\1+'
```

Where `[qrtpsdfghjklzxcvbnm]` just all consonants

All quotes from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression).

Comment: You can add the `-u` flag to `sort`, that way the use of `uniq` is superfluous. Also the `+` in the regex is unnecessary.

Comment: Thanks! I just copy all before `grep` from question. But without `+` it will 'catch' only 2 times repeated characters. Or may be I do not understand this phrase  *consecutive repeating*? Sorry English is not my mother language.

Comment: You only need _two_ consecutive letters in order to have consecutive repeating :-) For example, `Sssay` is matched by `grep -Ei '(<consonants>)\1'` no need for the `+`.

Comment: You are right :-)

Answer (score 0):

Consider a file (`name.txt`) contains the following,

```
abbcfgh
askgdf
rtdhher
ueiids
oofyf
asdgfhppn
aettdo
```

Now use of the following command will print strings with consecutive repeating consonants,

```bsh
$ cat name.txt | grep -iEv '([aeiou])\1+' | grep -iE '([a-z])\1+'

abbcfgh
rtdhher
asdgfhppn
aettdo
```

**How it works**

`grep -iEv '([aeiou])\1+'` discards strings with (using invert matching) consecutive repeating vowels. And the next `grep -iE '([a-z])\1+'` lists strings with consecutive repeating consonants.

In your case use,

```bsh
cat allnames.txt | cut -f5 | sort | uniq | grep -iEv '([aeiou])\1+' | grep -iE '([a-z])\1+'
```

**Special case**

The above will fail in a case there is some word with two consecutive consonant with two consecutive vowels. For example, `aeeoiffsa`. In such the following should be used,

```bsh
cat allnames.txt | cut -f5 | sort | uniq | grep -iE '([b-df-hj-np-tv-z])\1+'
```

Comment: I think the last grep is wrong. (Since it removes strings like `Eenna`, which does contain a consecutive consonant.) You can also use `sort -u` instead of `sort | uniq`.